# Raspberry Pi to PC over UART doesn't work

Tags: linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi, uart

I am trying to send/receive data over serial connection (GPIO UART pins) between a Raspberry Pi (B model, raspian wheezy) and any pc (tried a netbook and desktop, both running with win 7).

I followed all the stepts found in several tutorials like: http://codeandlife.com/2012/07/01/raspberry-pi-serial-console-with-max3232cpe/
to build a 5V to 3.3V converter. (unfortunately i can't post a pic yet)

The settings for ttyAMA0 in files 'cmdline' and 'inittab' are ok. (like described in many tutorials)

Connecting RX/TX on rpi direct works fine, so i can send text over GPIO pins and receive it. But as i connect it to a pc there is no way to read or write any data. Baudrate 9600 or 115200 doens't matter. (Hardware connection: rpi GPIO -> voltage converter -> serial USB adapter -> pc)
On pc i used Putty. On the rpi:

- 'echo text >> /dev/ttyAMA0' on the terminal
- Putty and
- minicom
  but no one had success

Is there anything i missed? Could you give me some advice i could look for please.

***some ideas:***

- Whereever i plug the usb into one of 3 available netbook USB ports the win device manager always say it's on COM3... shouldn't it change?
- is there a possibility to make some measurements inside the voltage converter wiring to insure that it's not a broken component in the hardware circuit? (i have no knowlegde of it's function)

Comment: When the UART's TxD output is idle, it should be `Marking`.  Check the RPi GPIO pin for +3V.  Check pin 2 of the female DB9 on the "voltage converter" (more appropriately called a "level shifter") for `Mark` at the RS232 level of about -12V.  GND is pin 5.

Comment: UART's Tx pin and GPIO VCC have nearly 3.3V. RS232 GND to Rx is 6.4V

Comment: *"RS232 GND to Rx is 6.4V"*  -- You need to explain what this means.  Voltage is measured in reference to ground.  Or is this your way of measuring -6.4V?  If this is the voltage on the red wire with respect to the blue (per the tutorial you linked), then this should actually be -13V per Maxim spec `T_OUT` on pin 14. Is the green wire connected to the RPi's TxD?

Comment: "Voltage is measured in reference to ground." yes thats how i did it! I found that i can send from my pc to rpi if i change Rx and Tx (red and brown cables) on the level shifter. But nothing the opposite way... (the characters i receive are not the ones i send). Yes green wire is connected to rpi's Tx.

Comment: ok i got it. It was the 9pin RS232 adapter which pins were soldered viewed from front side. But must be viewed from back to get it in the right direction...

Comment: *"9pin RS232 adapter"*  --  "Adapter" or connector?  *"But must be viewed from back..."* -- You are not (but should be) paying attention to the **gender** of the connector.  The *back* of the *female* DB9 has the same pin arrangement as the *front* of a *male* DB9.  Quality DB connectors should have the pin number markings on both the front and back.